# How do you make a flex item break to the next line?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic html markup, where i am trying to use minimal html wrappers to achieve the design. 
The `button` on the bottom should't align, it should always stay in the bottom.
So my goal is without adding more html wrappers, using flex, force a flex item(`button`) to drop to the next line. and the `block title` stay next to the image. 
You can see what i mean checking it on mobile breakpoints.
Here are the screenshots with `flex-wrap: wrap`
[image]

And here is with `flex-wrap: nowrap`
[image]

As you see, in first example button is in the bottom as it should be, but `block title` is dropped to the next line, And in the second example (`flex-wrap: wrap`) `block title` is positioned correct, but the button is not in the bottom.

Here is the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-dirac-3vwsnm?file=/index.html) and code example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  column-gap: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* //try nowrap */
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-image {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.headline {
  color: white;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="download.png" width="50px" class="logo-image" alt="img" />
  <span class="content">
        <h4 class="headline">
          Block Title
        </h4>
        <p class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente
          aliquid sit, cupiditate
        </p>
      </span>
  <div class="btn">
    <button>link</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your span a block level element and set flex-grow to 1 but set flex-basis to something small, like 50% so it tries to be 50% of the width but will grow to fit the  width. It then means when shrinking it will try to stay on the same line.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  column-gap: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
/* added this --v */
.content {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.logo-image {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.headline {
  color: white;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" width="50px" class="logo-image" alt="img" />
  <span class="content">
        <h4 class="headline">
          Block Title
        </h4>
        <p class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente
          aliquid sit, cupiditate
        </p>
      </span>
  <div class="btn">
    <button>link</button>
  </div>
</div>
```